# how to reference file by path in published c# visual studio build

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a file path which I access like this

```
string[] pathDirs = { Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..\\..\\")),
                "config", "file.txt" };
string pathToFile = Path.Combine(pathDirs);
```

When I run the build from within visual studio it gets the `config` directory from the root directory of the project but when I publish the build and run the program from the published build I get the error

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GA3VWRPE.G83\KDK3Q6QC.VP1\sv20..tion_333839f4362dc717_0001.0000_958d209d94853f42\config\file.txt'.
```

I'm unsure how to access this directory and file in the published build. How would I do this?

Comment: does the file actually exist in the published folder ? if not in visual studio Solution explorer, right click on that file for properties and set  `Copy To Output Directory` _Build Action_ property  to `Copy Always` or `Copy If Newer` and give it a shot ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the path to the executable, you can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, which could be incorporated into your code like:

```
string filePath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "..", "..", "config", "file.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ManiVI for that comment.

1. Go to Solution Explorer and click Show All Files
2. Go to file.txt, right-click and select Include In Project
3. in Properties
4. Build Action: Content,
5. Copy To Output Directory: Copy always

Once I followed these steps the published program managed to find file.txt.